# What is response headers format to output OpenAPI docs on FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, openapi, response-headers

Let me know someone way to output header name

I wrote response the following code,

```
    responses={
    st.HTTP_200_OK: {
        "model": main_response_data,
        "description": "main response data",
        "headers": [{"header_name":"response_key", "description": "Response key", "type": "string"}]
    },
```

But after run, OpenAPI document output "0" at header name

```
headers
Name       Description         Type
------------------------------------------
0           Response key         string
```

Answer (score 2):

`headers` [should be a dictionary with the HTTP-header as a key](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#responseObject):

```
"headers": {"response_key": {"description": "Response key", "type": "string"}}
```

When you define it as a list instead, the index will be used as the key - i.e. why you're getting 0.